# Free/open-source self-hosted CRM with dashboard and SMTP capabilities

Tags: open-source, crm

I'm looking for free and open source CRMs which I could host in my server. I have a simple need of lead tracking and converting it into sales. I have sales representatives which are communicating with clients; each of them should see what they are entering into the dashboard and the admin should be able to track all the sales and leads in a single dashboard. If it can be configured with SMTPs and other APIs then that would be great.

Comment: https://www.selecthub.com/customer-relationship-management/big-crm-comparison-chart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search the forum, you will find many answers on CRM.

One you could explore is [SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/) is a fork/successor/improvement on the old community version of SugarCRM.

- You can tracks contacts, leads, etc.
- You can record notes/calls etc, against each contact/company.
- You can add extra fields via its "Studio".
- It is PHP/MySql based, and Open source.
- It probably has much more than you need. But you can hide or disable some of the modules.